# Select statement by group by total

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have two tables `Contact` and `Invoice` linked by `ContactId`

Please see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55fe5/1)

I am selecting all the contact who have spend more than 2500 per any year and the query works fine.

I wanted it to display in a below format. 
[image]

Any help on this please using `sql-server`. I can easily do this using crystal-report cross tab, but trying to do thing only using sql-server

Comment: Changing how data is displayed is usually managed in the presentation layer rather than in SQL, e.g. an SSRS matrix would easily handle the data in the format you already have it and display it in the format you require. Where do you want to display the results?

Comment: @GarethD: Inputting this in to a excel will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), then [UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) your data from your original query to get it in the desired format:

```
WITH T AS
(   SELECT  c.ContactID, 
            ContactName = c.Name,
            Year = DATEPART(YEAR, i.InvDate),
            Invoices = CAST(COUNT(i.InvoiceID) AS FLOAT),
            InvTotal = CAST(SUM(i.InvTotal) AS FLOAT)
    FROM    Invoice AS i
            INNER JOIN dbo.Contact AS c
                ON c.ContactID = i.InvContactID
    GROUP BY c.ContactID, c.Name, DATEPART(YEAR, i.InvDate)
    HAVING SUM(i.InvTotal) > 2000
)
SELECT  ContactName = CASE WHEN pvt.Measure = 'InvTotal' THEN '' ELSE pvt.ContactName END,
        pvt.Measure,
        [2012] = ISNULL(pvt.[2012], 0),
        [2013] = ISNULL(pvt.[2013], 0),
        [2014] = ISNULL(pvt.[2014], 0)
FROM    T
        UNPIVOT 
        (   Value
            FOR Measure IN ([Invoices], [InvTotal])
        ) AS upvt
        PIVOT
        (   SUM(Value)
            FOR [Year] IN ([2012], [2013], [2014])
        ) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.ContactName, Measure;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55fe5/7)**